# Spring and JSF - Dependency Injection fails ServiceBean can not be loaded

Tags: spring, jsf, dependency-injection

i currently hang up in the Spring and JSF Integration. I think i misconfigured something and i can not see what exactly. I get a NULL Pointer Exception because of the Service Tier is not going to be loaded by the JSF Bean. My configuration is the following:

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.speterit.auftragssystem.beans.MitarbeiterBean.getMitarbeiterList(MitarbeiterBean.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:484)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:553)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1293)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:446)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TableRenderer.encodeBegin(TableRenderer.java:77)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:824)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.encodeBegin(UIData.java:936)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1661)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1666)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1666)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

default.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<h:head>

</h:head>
</head>
<h:body>
    #{mitarbeiterBean.getServiceMitarbeiter() ne null ? "true" : "false"}<br />
    <h:dataTable value="#{mitarbeiterBean.getMitarbeiterList()}" var="m">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Vorname</f:facet>
                        #{m.vorname}
                </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Nachname</f:facet>
                        #{m.nachname}
                </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Geburtsdatum</f:facet>
                        #{m.geburtsdatum}
                </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:body>
```

The evaluation `#{mitarbeiterBean.getServiceMitarbeiter() ne null ? "true" : "false"}<br />` is giving false when I execute the code without the datatable part.

MitarbeiterBean.java

```
package com.speterit.auftragssystem.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import com.speterit.auftragssystem.data.model.Mitarbeiter;
import com.speterit.auftragssystem.data.service.IServiceMitarbeiter;

@ManagedBean(name = "mitarbeiterBean")
@RequestScoped
public class MitarbeiterBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public IServiceMitarbeiter serviceMitarbeiter;
    public String vorname;
    public String nachname;
    public Date geburtsdatum;

    public List<Mitarbeiter> getMitarbeiterList()
    {
        return getServiceMitarbeiter().retrieveAllMitarbeiter();
    }

    public void addMitarbeiter()
    {
        Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter = new Mitarbeiter(getVorname(), getNachname(),
                getGeburtsdatum());

        getServiceMitarbeiter().createMitarbeiter(mitarbeiter);

        clearForm();
    }

    public void clearForm()
    {
        setVorname("");
        setNachname("");
        setGeburtsdatum(null);
    }

    public String getVorname()
    {
        return vorname;
    }

    public void setVorname(String vorname)
    {
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }

    public String getNachname()
    {
        return nachname;
    }

    public void setNachname(String nachname)
    {
        this.nachname = nachname;
    }

    public Date getGeburtsdatum()
    {
        return geburtsdatum;
    }

    public void setGeburtsdatum(Date geburtsdatum)
    {
        this.geburtsdatum = geburtsdatum;
    }

    public IServiceMitarbeiter getServiceMitarbeiter()
    {
        return serviceMitarbeiter;
    }

    public void setServiceMitarbeiter(IServiceMitarbeiter serviceMitarbeiter)
    {
        this.serviceMitarbeiter = serviceMitarbeiter;
    }
}
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <beans:property name="configurationClass"
            value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Model Declaration -->
    <beans:bean id="Mitarbeiter" class="com.speterit.auftragssystem.data.model.Mitarbeiter"/>

    <!-- DAO Declaration -->
    <beans:bean id="DaoMitarbeiter" class="com.speterit.auftragssystem.data.dao.DaoMitarbeiter">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Service Declaration -->
    <beans:bean id="ServiceMitarbeiter" class="com.speterit.auftragssystem.data.service.ServiceMitarbeiter">
        <beans:property name="daoMitarbeiter" ref="DaoMitarbeiter" />
    </beans:bean>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>mitarbeiterBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.speterit.auftragssystem.beans.MitarbeiterBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
        <managed-property>
            <property-name>serviceMitarbeiter</property-name>
            <value>#{ServiceMitarbeiter}</value>
        </managed-property>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

IServiceMitarbeiter.java

package com.speterit.auftragssystem.data.service;

```
import java.util.List;

import com.speterit.auftragssystem.data.dao.IDaoMitarbeiter;
import com.speterit.auftragssystem.data.model.Mitarbeiter;

public interface IServiceMitarbeiter
{
    public List<Mitarbeiter> retrieveAllMitarbeiter();
    public Mitarbeiter retrieveMitarbeiter(long personalnummer);
    public Mitarbeiter createMitarbeiter(Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter);
    public Mitarbeiter updateMitarbeiter(Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter);
    public IDaoMitarbeiter getDaoMitarbeiter();
    public void setDaoMitarbeiter(IDaoMitarbeiter daoMitarbeiter);
}
```

ServiceMitarbeiter.java

```
package com.speterit.auftragssystem.data.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.speterit.auftragssystem.data.dao.IDaoMitarbeiter;
import com.speterit.auftragssystem.data.model.Mitarbeiter;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class ServiceMitarbeiter implements IServiceMitarbeiter
{
    IDaoMitarbeiter daoMitarbeiter;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Mitarbeiter> retrieveAllMitarbeiter()
    {
        return daoMitarbeiter.getAll();
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Mitarbeiter retrieveMitarbeiter(long personalnummer)
    {
        return daoMitarbeiter.getByPersonalnummer(personalnummer);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Mitarbeiter createMitarbeiter(Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter)
    {
        return daoMitarbeiter.create(mitarbeiter);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public Mitarbeiter updateMitarbeiter(Mitarbeiter mitarbeiter)
    {
        return daoMitarbeiter.persistOrMerge(mitarbeiter);
    }

    public IDaoMitarbeiter getDaoMitarbeiter()
    {
        return daoMitarbeiter;
    }

    public void setDaoMitarbeiter(IDaoMitarbeiter daoMitarbeiter)
    {
        this.daoMitarbeiter = daoMitarbeiter;
    }
}
```

I'm happy for every fast clue :) Because i got no idea anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver` your class needs to be a
simple Spring component. Remove `@ManagedBean` and add `@Component` annotations.

You've created another instance of `MitarbeiterBean` managed by JSF via `@ManagedBean` annotation and it is not the same bean that is managed by Spring so the `serviceMitarbeiter` field is not injected. Just forget about JSF managed beans and use Spring components in JSF.

Also replace `javax.faces.bean` sope annotations with Spring `@Scope`.

e.g. `@RequestScoped` -> `@Scope("request")`

Comment: Hi, what shall i use instead of @ManagedProperty? Because @Autowire also fails. With an NullPointerException

Comment: Me again i now found the mistake when i integrate JSF to my web.xml i deleted the reference to servlet-context.xml where everything is defined as shown above i added it again and now is everything fine :) Thanks without you i wouldn't seen it

Comment: What are you actually do is wireing Spring bean into JSF bean via EL `#{ServiceMitarbeiter}`. What is more you do it in `faces-config.xml`. Why don't you just put beans to JSF via the same EL and drop one of two containers. You have more configuration than application code now. You can also use `@ManagedProperty` instead of  xml configuration. It is the strangest config I've ever seen actually. I'd suggest to review it.

Comment: I reviewed it allready the code was only this way because of my hopeless tries to make it work. Now i rolled it back to the way it was before. And did the correct changes but you are allright :) Now i have a @Autowire in the JSF Bean so also in the Spring Context and the faces-config.xml is empty except the el-resolver definition. This is my first project where i use JSF and Spring together productive so there was more try then understand at the end.

Comment: That is a good design. I was using such stack recently and was quite happy. You can run it for development on Jetty (with maven plugin, no installation required). You'd probably face lack of view scope in Spring, but just look it up on Stackoverflow. I guess I've found view scope implementation in PrimeFaces.

Comment: Yes i looked yesterday at the concept of view Scoping with PrimeFaces. But i wanted to keep it more simple then this and thats the reason why i decided to take a PostConstructor because it is more builtin.